# To use a read-only property or a method?

Tags: c#, .net, class, methods, properties

I need to expose the "*is mapped?*" state of an instance of a class.  The outcome is determined by a basic check. It is **not** simply exposing the value of a field.  I am unsure as to whether I should use a read-only property or a method.

**Read-only property:**

```
public bool IsMapped
{
    get
    {
        return MappedField != null;
    }
}
```

**Method:**

```
public bool IsMapped()
{
    return MappedField != null;
}
```

I have read MSDN's [Choosing Between Properties and Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) but I am still unsure.

Comment: I think sysexpands comment in James' answer is your answer. When you look back on your code or other developers look at it; having it as a property almost certainly shows it is only returning a value relating to a field. No sane developer would put excessive functionality into a property right? On the other hand, 10 answers all saying RO property is surely the same answer

Comment: So what does reading `MappedField` entail? Is it a simple read of a variable, or is it a potentially expensive operation or one with side effects (e.g. lazy loading)?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The C# standard says

> § 8.7.4
>
> A **property** is a member that provides access to a characteristic of an object or a class. Examples of properties include the length of a string, the size of a font, the caption of a window, the name of a customer, and so on. Properties are a natural extension of fields. Both are named members with associated types, and the syntax for accessing fields and properties is the same. However, unlike fields, properties do not denote storage locations. Instead, properties have accessors that specify the statements to be executed when their values are read or written.

while as methods are defined as

> § 8.7.3
>
> A **method** is a member that implements a computation or action that can be performed by an object or class. Methods have a (possibly empty) list of formal parameters, a return value (unless the method’s return-type is void ), and are either static or non-static.

**Properties** and **methods** are used to realize [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Properties encapsulate data, methods encapsulate logic. And this is why you should prefer a read-only property if you are exposing data. In your case there is no logic that modifies the internal state of your object. You want to *provide access to a characteristic of an object*.

Whether an instance of your object `IsMapped` or not is a characteristic of your object. It contains a check, but that's why you have properties to access it. Properties can be defined using logic, but they should not expose logic. Just like the example mentioned in the first quote: Imagine the `String.Length` property. Depending on the implementation, it may be that this property loops through the string and counts the characters. It also does perform an operation, but "from the outside" it just give's an statement over the internal state/characteristics of the object.

Comment: "_You want to provide access to a characteristic of an object._" - this is what I was looking for.  This is the most complete answer with the appropriate MSDN references.  Thanks.

Comment: While not a hard and fast rule, I would tend to also use a method when the computation time to return a property is non trivial. Properties should return immediately.

Comment: +1 for clear focusing on semantics and not on formal criteria

Answer (score 23):

I would use the property, because there is no real "doing" (action), no side effects and it's not too complex.

Comment: I wish coders say such "I don't use *** because there are no arguments, why do I neeed it" as frequently as possible.

Answer (score 14):

I personally believe that a `method` should do something or perform some action. You are not performing anything inside `IsMapped` so it should be a `property`

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for a property. Mostly because the first senctence on the referenced MSDN-article:

> In general, methods represent actions and properties represent data.

Answer (score 5):

In this case it seems pretty clear to me that it should be a property. It's a simple check, no logic, no side effects, no performance impact. It doesn't get much simpler than that check.

**Edit:**

Please note that if there *was* any of the above mentioned and you would put it into a method, that method should include a strong verb, not an auxiliary verb like is or has. A method *does* something. You could name it VerifyMapping or DetermineMappingExistance or something else as long as it starts with a verb.

Comment: But `MappedField != null` is by definition a logic statement.

Comment: You assume here that reading `MappedField` is simple, fast and has no side effects. We don't know that to be true.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Obviously, he could have implemented a custom operator != that formats his hard disk, but you can break all things in many ways. As long as nothing is specified, I will assume that what I see is standard compliant.

Answer (score 5):

I think this line in your link is the answer

> methods represent actions and properties represent data.

There is no action here, just a piece of data. So it's a Property.

Comment: But in the same light, then why is `IEnumerable.Count()` a method?

Comment: It does a count...(an action)

Comment: But I am also doing an action... a `null` check

Comment: You are checking a piece of data, not performing an action on it. - If based on the result you did something else or performed a calc or something, then it would be a method.

Comment: IEnumerable.Count() is an extension method which basically walks through the collection and counts contains elements. On the other hand, IList.Count is a property because it doesn't traverse the list - list already knows its count and simply returns it from the property.

Comment: IEnumerable.Count() doesn't exist. Count() is an extension method, found in the static class Enumerable, and 1) extension properties don't exist and 2) Count() is likely to be time consuming (especially in complex LINQ queries).

Comment: @sysexpand: `IEnumerable.Count()` is an extension method, that's right, but the only reason why it is an extension **method** is, because there are not extension **properties**. `IList.Count` could traverse the whole list, depending on the interface implementation. It is impossible for an interface to define it's implementation - however it is possible to decide whether or not an field of an object is an characteristic (data/property) or an operation (method).

Answer (score 4):

In situations/languages where you have access to both of these constructs, the general divide is as follows:

- If the request is for something the object *has*, use a property (or a field).
- If the request is for the result of something the object *does*, use a method.

A little more specifically, a property is to be used to access, in read and/or write fashion, a data member that is (for consuming purposes) owned by the object exposing the property. Properties are better than fields because the data doesn't have to exist in persistent form all the time (they allow you to be "lazy" about calculation or retrieval of this data value), and they're better than methods for this purpose because you can still use them in code as if they were public fields.

Properties should not, however, result in side effects (with the possible, understandable exception of setting a variable meant to persist the value being returned, avoiding expensive recalculation of a value needed many times); they should, all other things being equal, return a deterministic result (so NextRandomNumber is a bad conceptual choice for a property) and the calculation should not result in the alteration of any state data that would affect other calculations (for instance, getting PropertyA and PropertyB in that order should not return any different result than getting PropertyB and then PropertyA).

A method, OTOH, is conceptually understood as performing some operation and returning the result; in short, it does something, which may extend beyond the scope of computing a return value. Methods, therefore, are to be used when an operation that returns a value has additional side effects. The return value may still be the result of some calculation, but the method may have computed it non-deterministically (GetNextRandomNumber()), or the returned data is in the form of a unique instance of an object, and calling the method again produces a different instance even if it may have the same data (GetCurrentStatus()), or the method may alter state data such that doing exactly the same thing twice in a row produces different results (EncryptDataBlock(); many encryption ciphers work this way by design to ensure encrypting the same data twice in a row produces different ciphertexts).

Answer (score 3):

If at any point you'll need to add parameters in order to get the value, then you need a method. Otherwise you need a property

Comment: With this definition, what about an indexed property?

Comment: If that value has major part in the object, then yes we might.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO , the first read-only property is correct because IsMapped as a Attribute of your object, and you're not performing an action (only an evaluation), but at the end of the day consistancy with your existing codebase probably counts for more than semantics.... unless this is a uni assignment

Answer (score 2):

I'll agree with people here in saying that because it is obtaining data, and has no side-effects, it should be a property.

To expand on that, I'd also accept some side-effects with a setter (but not a getter) if the side-effects made sense to someone "looking at it from the outside".

One way to think about it is that methods are verbs, and properties are adjectives (meanwhile, the objects themselves are nouns, and static objects are abstract nouns).

The only exception to the verb/adjective guideline is that it can make sense to use a method rather than a property when obtaining (or setting) the information in question can be very expensive: Logically, such a feature should probably still be a property, but people are used to thinking of properties as low-impact performance-wise and while there's no real reason why that should always be the case, it could be useful to highlight that `GetIsMapped()` is relatively heavy perform-wise if it in fact was.

At the level of the running code, there's absolutely no difference between calling a property and calling an equivalent method to get or set; it's all about making life easier for the person writing code that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect property as it only is returning the detail of a field. On the other hand I would expect

```
MappedFields[] mf;
public bool IsMapped()
{
     mf.All(x => x != null);
}
```

Comment: In this example you are performing multiple `null` checks.  How is this logically different from mine, where I am also performing a `null` check?

Comment: Its different as you do not know the answer until you have queryed  every member of mf

Answer (score 0):

you should use the property because c# has properties for this reason